# How to ensure if atleast one checkbox is selected for multiselect jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I am using the jquery multiselect [plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/).  Right now I am checking if the user has selected any checkbox or not with the below code.

```
function fntemp()
{
var values = $("select").val();
alert(values);
if(!values){
alert("Please select atleast one value from the dropdown.");    
 }
}
```

But this does not work when we click "Check All" link. Any suggestions?

Comment: This [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024810/multiselect-jquery-check-my-multiple-select-if-at-least-one-options-should-be/46024908#46024908) has the perfect solution for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, you can get an array of all the checked checkboxes using

```
$("select").multiselect("getChecked");
```

I assume you can therefore do something like:

```
if ($("select").multiselect("getChecked").length == 0)
{
   alert("Please select atleast one value from the dropdown.");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Should work:

```
var test = $("select option:selected").length;
```