# Multiselect, Jquery: Check my multiple select if at least one options should be selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

Hi I will summarize my problem I hope you would understand.

**Main Goal:** To check if at least one of the options is selected before hitting the select button. else, If select button is clicked without choosing at least one options, it will show a message of "Please choose at least one options".

**Purpose:** I have reasons in my other codes that needed a select button instead of just selecting multiple selects and doesn't need a button.

The form looks like this:

[image]

**SIMPLE HTML CODE:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  // My Select Id is monthlymonth

  <label for="monthlymonth" class="col-sm-4 control-label">For the Month Of: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-6" id=monthlymonthdiv>
      <select class="form-control" name="monthlymonth[]" id="monthlymonth" multiple>
          <option> October </option>
          <option> November </option>
          <option> December </option>
      </select>
   </div>

   /My Select button, Id is monthsubmit.
   <input style="text-align:center; width: 60px;" type="button" id="monthsubmit" name="monthsubmit" value="Select">

   <input style="text-align:center; width: 60px;" type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="Clear">
</div>
```

**Now for my JQuery:**

```
$("#monthsubmit").unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
  if (// code that checks if no options is selected at least one)
  {
    alert('Please choose at least one month');
  }
  else
  {
    // my other codes
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this may help you `if ($('#monthlymonth').get(0).selectedIndex == -1)`

```js
$("#monthsubmit").on('click', function() {
     if ($('#monthlymonth').get(0).selectedIndex == -1)
     {
       alert('Please choose at least one month');
     }
     else
     {
       // my other codes
     }
   });

$("#clear").on('click', function() {
    $("#monthlymonth option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

  <label for="monthlymonth" class="col-sm-4 control-label">For the Month Of: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-6" id=monthlymonthdiv>
      <select class="form-control" name="monthlymonth[]" id="monthlymonth" multiple>
          <option> October </option>
          <option> November </option>
          <option> December </option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <input style="text-align:center; width: 60px;" type="button" id="monthsubmit" name="monthsubmit" value="Select">

   <input style="text-align:center; width: 60px;" type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="Clear">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome happy coding

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jquery, the best way to check the value of an input is with the "val()" function. 
If nothing was selected it will return a value of null.

here is an example :

```js
$("#monthsubmit").unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
  if (!$("#monthlymonthdiv").val())
  {
    alert('Please choose at least one month');
  }
  else
  {
    // my other codes
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

  <label for="monthlymonth" class="col-sm-4 control-label">For the Month Of: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-6" id=monthlymonthdiv>
      <select class="form-control" name="monthlymonth[]" id="monthlymonth" multiple>
          <option> October </option>
          <option> November </option>
          <option> December </option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <input style="text-align:center; width: 60px;" type="button" id="monthsubmit" name="monthsubmit" value="Select">

   <input style="text-align:center; width: 60px;" type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="Clear">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a simplified version.

```js
$("#monthsubmit").click(function(){
    if (!$("#monthlymonth option:selected").length) {
        alert('Please choose at least one month');
    }
});

$("#clear").click(function(){
    $("#monthlymonth option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">

  <label for="monthlymonth" class="col-sm-4 control-label">For the Month Of: </label>
  <div class="col-sm-6" id=monthlymonthdiv>
      <select class="form-control" name="monthlymonth[]" id="monthlymonth" multiple>
          <option> October </option>
          <option> November </option>
          <option> December </option>
      </select>
   </div>

   <input style="text-align:center; width: 60px;" type="button" id="monthsubmit" name="monthsubmit" value="Select">

   <input style="text-align:center; width: 60px;" type="button" id="clear" name="clear" value="Clear">
</div>
```